# Wrap jQuery Event Listeners in Boolean If Statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

So here is my situation... I want to do something to this affect:

```
var myBool = false;
function flipBool(){
     if(myBool){
          myBool = false;
     } else {
          myBool = true;
     }
}
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     if(myBool){
          jQuery("div.someDiv").hover(...)...;
     } else {//don't do the hover stuff...}
});
```

Is there an easy way to do this? Because things are just not working how they should from how I understand it.

Comment: Why not do `myBool = !myBool` instead of that `if-else`?

Comment: It was a quick example... this is meant to figure out if I can wrap event listeners in if statements or not in some way... not critique how I set a boolean variable.

Comment: Yep I understand that. Was more of a nitpicky comment.

Comment: Where, and especiall *when*, is `flipBool` called?

Answer (score 0):

You defined the function `flipBool()` but never called it, and you should move the `if(myBool){}` into the `hover`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

     flipBool();//reverses myBool

     jQuery("div.someDiv").hover(function(){
            if(myBool){
                //will be executed only if myBool is originally false
            } else {
                //will be executed only if myBool is originally true
            }
     });         
});
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/erkaner/yqgL6hen/

Comment: Ah I wrote that example fairly quick... assume I ran it.

Comment: Ah I see, let me give that a go, thanks man. If it works, I'll make you the best answer :D

Comment: When it's true it does not perform the hover. Any idea why? False works dandy! Also, I suppose I should tell you I have my hover set up to have two functions (one for on hover, and one for off hover)

Comment: @BradMash because it will be executed only if myBool is originally false. can you check my comments?

Comment: I am manually overriding the value of the boolean variable through Firebug. When I set it to true, and then try to hover, the hover code is not running... it won't even run a simple log command on hover when set to true. Also, I put the if statement inside the hover like you suggested.